# How to split all elements of list in python?

Tags: python-2.5

I have a list of form:

```
list = ['1.25','5.26','8.55']
```

I want this list to get splitted as :

```
list = [1.25],[5.26],[8.55]
```

so, could you please help how can i have above stated splitted list using python.
I am new to python So, apologies if its something very common. need help.

Comment: `list = [1.25],[5.26],[8.55]` this line will return compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ['1.25','5.26','8.55']
newList = []
for i in list:
    newList.append([float(i)])
list=newList
```

The *list* is now a list-of-lists.

Also, try not to name your variables as *list*, *tuple*, etc. as they are reserved words. Give your list a new name, a meaningful one would be self-documenting and will further help you in the long-run.